# Is `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` subset of `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)`?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I know, `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID])` and `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers identifiers: [UUID])` have different parameters. But, for example if I got all possible peripherals by using these two methods, would peripherals retrieved from `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` be a subset of peripherals retrieved from `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)`?

Comment: Maybe. It would depend whether the array of peripheral identifiers you passed to `retrievePeripherals` included all of the identifiers of the connected peripherals offering the specified services.

Comment: @Paulw11: Yes, If I had all of the IDs of peripherals and all of the IDs of the services. Imagine that I (theoretically) generated all possible UUIDs.

Comment: Then yes, a connected peripheral will be known to the device, so it will be returned by `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)`